# GridFS upload file implementation details

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

<s>Is it possible to allow UPLOAD-only role to user?  Does GridFS perform update onto fs.files during upload?</s>

Does GridFS implementation perform any "update" or "read" action onto "fs.files" or "fs.chunks" collection during file upload?

Comment: This is really actually a "roles" permissions things and therefore a question for [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) and not here. But the big hint here is there are "no GridFS permissions" and the reason why is because "GridFS is not a database feature", it's just software. All that is really happening is reading/wriitng/updating documents in a collection as far as the MongoDB server is concerned. So you basically are looking for something like "insertOnly" if no modifications or reading are meant to be allowed.

Comment: yes, that's why i'm asking "does GridFS perform update onto fs.files during upload" - i'm thinking about setting "insert" permission onto fs.files and fs.chunks

Comment: That's why I responded. "This has nothing to do with GridFS". Driver level software has nothing to do with database permissions. That is what you need to understand. As well as "database permissions" has nothing to do with programming, and therefore off-topic. There is a site. You got the link.

Comment: No there is no as such API to perform update on your data for GridFS ie in `fs.files`

Comment: Anyone can update fs.files using collections API

Comment: Changed the question to make it more precise...